# Change format of column in R

Tags: r, posixct

In my table I have a timestamp column in which i want to change the format. I already tried multiple things but it doesnt work. I also can not find examples to change the format in the whole column. First i converted the column to POSIXct then Ive tried to adjsut the format:

```
#timestamp as POSIXct and lane as numeric
Flows_ALM_2019 %>%
 mutate(timestamp = as.POSIXct(timestamp),lane = as.numeric(lane)) -> Flows_ALM_2019

#remove seconds from time in timestamp column
df <- strftime(timestamp, format= "%Y-%m-%d %H:%m")
```

after trying:
df_2019_tsb$timestamp <- format(df_2019_tsb$timestamp,format= "%Y-%m-%d %H:%m")

This is what I had:

[image]

and now it changed to:

[image]

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `format` :

```
Flows_ALM_2019$timestamp <- format(Flows_ALM_2019$timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%m")
```

Or with `strftime`.

```
Flows_ALM_2019$timestamp <- strftime(Flows_ALM_2019$timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%m")
```

This is assuming that `timestamp` column is of class `POSIXct` in your data.